# redirect using button onclick

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Laravel framework and the blade templating engine.

What I would like to do, is have 2 buttons in my view, when clicked will redirect you to another view. The code I tried was:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="{{ Redirect::to('users.index') }}">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may try this (assuming this code is in a blade template):

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("users/index") }}'">Button</button>
```

However, `{{ url('users/index') }}` will print the `URL` so, it'll become something like this in the browser:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='http://example.com/users/index'">Button</button>
```

It means that you have a route declared something like this:

```
Route::get('users/index', array('uses' => 'UserController@index', 'as' => 'users.index'));
```

In this case, may also use:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ route("users.index") }}'">Button</button>
```

The output will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you would need to basically use the URL helper to generate the URL (same as just putting something like http://yoursite.com/users instead of the PHP helper):

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ URL::route('users.index'); }}'">Button</button>
```

Although I don't see why you can't just use an "a href" tag instead of the button, like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('users.index'); }}">My button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also style an href tag as a button. For example
`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('users.create' }}">Create</a>`
This helps to avoid mixing javascript and blade directives.```